# WPF C# Drawing line by using coordinates of buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, line

I have 2 buttons created in code behind ,I am trying to draw a line that connects them by getting the button coordinates, but it doesn't work the way that I wanted , I am new to this , am I doing this the right way?

I searched internet for line connecting 2 controls, but I just want a simple one that make use of coordinates to connect them .

Here are my codes :

```
 Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Content = "Hello";
        btn1.Width = 150;
        btn1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        wrapPanel1.Children.Add(btn1);
        btn1.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(btn1_MouseDown);


        Button btn2 = new Button();
        btn2.Content = "World";
        btn2.Width = 150;
        btn2.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        btn2.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(btn1_MouseDown);
        wrapPanel1.Children.Add(btn2);

    private void ShowLocation(ContentControl element)
     {
    var location = element.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
   MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
                                  "{2}'s location is ({0}, {1})", 
                                   location.X, 
                                    location.Y, 
                                   element.Content));

   Line redLine = new Line();
   redLine.X1 = location.X;
   redLine.Y1 = location.Y;
   redLine.X2 = 323;
   redLine.Y2 = 167;


   //Create a red Brush
   SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
   redBrush.Color = Colors.Red;

   //Set Line's width and color
   redLine.StrokeThickness = 4;
   redLine.Stroke = redBrush;

   // Add line to the Grid.
   wrapPanel1.Children.Add(redLine);

     }

  private void btn1_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var element = sender as ContentControl;
     if (element != null)
     {
         ShowLocation(element);
     }


 }
```

As you notice the X2 and Y2 coordinates I just random giving it a number but the X1 and Y1 is suppose to be drawn from the button but it is not.

The line is appearing somewhere else away from the button, but the coords I use are the coords of the button.

Also, I have to dynamically create many buttons from db, This is just testing out yet I am stuck here.

__EDIT____

trying out with 1 button , i realise when maximize and minimize , the coords are different , this is how it looks like , the button seems to increase its height everytime i click on it to generate the line .

[image]

i want the line to start from the end of the button width at the side , if its not possible , it will be good for the button to overlap the line but is that possible?

Comment: The line isn't a random line it is probably pointing to your screen coordinate rather than local to the window (Impossible to say without a screenshot). winforms has a location property.. tryin to find similar for wpf..

Comment: i can post the screenshot here

Comment: try using `btn.PointFromScreen(new Point(0, 0));`, just been testing with it and it seems to be correct but with negative x and y.. just not sure if thats needed

Comment: Posted a ss . And  cannot convert to double if i use that

Comment: That returns a point with x and y are you using pointfromscreen.x etc? In your screenshot the line looks to be 323 right from the start of the line and 167 upwards

Comment: but i set my X1Y1 location as the same coords as the button , it should start from the button i suppose?

Comment: I think it needs to be the difference between the button positions perhaps.. I would look into pointfromscreenthough as that should return the buttons position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that WPF mostly uses layout-based positioning (`Grid`, `DockPanel`, etc), instead of Windows Forms, which is coordinate-based. This means, that real location of left top element's corner depends from layout control being used and its current settings (and yes, this usually blows up your mind, if you are very new to WPF).

If you want to manage position of elements by coordinates in WPF, then you should use [`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) (you can easily translate this sample from XAML to C#):

```
    <Canvas>
        <Button Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="20" Height="20" Content="A"/>
        <Button Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" Width="20" Height="20" Content="B"/>
        <Line Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="30" X2="20" Y2="20" StrokeThickness="4" Stroke="Red"/>
    </Canvas>
```

[image]

Comment: interesting , i never use canvas before ( new to programming ) by setting only the X2 Y2 u can connect them? i tot u need 2 coordinates?

Comment: Indeed, there are two coordinates. :) `X1` and `Y1` use their defaults (zeros), but `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties are setting (left, top) for line relative to canvas (left, top).

Comment: i don't really get it , how u know the coordinates of A and B . Please bear with me if i am asking a easy question , How do u get the coordinates of A and B ?

Comment: And what if i were to put 2 stack panels in the canvas , and each stackpanel consist of dynamic created- buttons in code behind , do we still able to get the coordinates of the button even its in a stackpanel that resides in the canvas?

Comment: @user2376998: I set coordinates of left top corner for every UI element directly with attached properties, `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`. Then its just simple arithmetic: button `A` has coordinates (10,10) and size (20,20). Thus, line should start from (10+20,10+20), or (30,30); respectively, for button `B`- (50,50), size (20,20), hence, line should end at (50,50). To achieve this, I must subtract line start position from line end position, (50-30,50-30), or (20,20). (20,20) its a line's end point, relative to its start point.

Comment: thanks for explaining , so i assume buttons need to reside in the canvas for this to be done? what if my buttons are inside a stackpanel that resides inside a canvas?

Comment: @user2376998: about `StackPanel`. No, `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` affects `UIElement` position only if its parent is `Canvas`. If you will place any element in some layout control, element will be positioned using settings of that control, not `Canvas` settings. But you can nest `Canvas` into another `Canvas`.